# IntelliSense compile errors not updating after initial parse in VS2015/2017 Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio

After a BSOD (irql not less or equal) under Win7 coding in visual studio got next to impossible as compile errors are no longer updated.

If I open a .cs file it does seem to parse it and report compile errors, but thats it. If I correct the error, it is still being displayed and if I were to produce new compile errors they are no longer reported.

I then upgraded to VS 2017 community which has the exact same issue. A complete uninstallation and reinstallation had no effect.

[Edit:] I'm referring to the inline error reporting in the form of red wiggly lines

Comment: If you explicitly build, does that update everything? I've certainly not seen "live" updates to the error list for quite a while in VS2017 (possibly never?) so I wonder whether it's been removed as a feature.

Comment: Yes explicit builds show the errors, and i'm not talking about the error list but the inline error reporting (red wiggly lines)

Comment: Ah, interesting - it's probably worth editing the question to make that clearer.